# unterminated string constant error in serialized json string

Tags: javascript

I need to send a serialized data as parameter in a javascript function as shown below.

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="fncname('{"data":"testval"}';)">
```

I am getting error unterminated string constant.

Can anyone help me to find out a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to html encode your attribute to avoid conflicting quotes.

```
<input type="button" id="btn1" onclick="fncname('{&quot;data&quot;:&quot;testval&quot;}')">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZbYR/